# Need all scope access for Xero Standard Web APP

Tags: xero-api, xero

We created a **XERO Web App** (Standard web application) and while executing the authorization token API we are getting on below scopes:

> "scope": "app.connections marketplace.billing"

We need all to grant scopes access so we can execute as much API from our system.

I know custom connection has all those options to grant scope access but my application would be available in Singapore and custom application is not available for Singapore.

Please help me, with how I can get all-scope access for the Web Standard App so I can execute as much as APIs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using OAuth 2.0 you will need to use the web based authentication system for the initial connection. However once this has been established and authenticated by a user, if you've included the offline_access scope in your Authentication, your app will benefit from Access and Refresh Tokens. Refresh Tokens can be used to refresh Access Tokens, without user intervention.

Refresh Tokens are single use, and will last for 60 days or until used. On a Refresh Call you will receive both a new Access Token and Refresh Token, allowing you to use the new Refresh Token on your next Refresh Call. In case a response is lost, Refresh Tokens also have a 30 minute grace period where the same token can be used as many times as you require in the first 30 minutes after their first use. The only time the user would need to interact would be if your app was to lose track of the tokens. In this scenario the web based authentication system would be re-used. You can look at the link in my previous reply for more information.

If you are still stuck you can contact Xero Support [here](https://developer.xero.com/contact-xero-developer-platform-support)

Comment: Suddenly THe above authorization stopped working, It was working but not giving error sometime: invalid_grant OR unauthorized_client

Comment: Please can you contact Xero Support using this link https://developer.xero.com/contact-xero-developer-platform-support

Comment: Thanks we contact with Xero team and they are figuring the solution if the issue

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are using the client_credentials method for getting the access tokens. You need to use the authorization_code method instead.

See the link below for more information:

[OAuth 2.0 for web app](https://developer.xero.com/documentation/guides/oauth2/auth-flow/#1-send-a-user-to-authorize-your-app)

Comment: I tried that link and the page and I assigned business to that app. but what next how do I need to do to get an API token, Please GUide

Comment: Hey Sallyhornet, I got the token by the link.
thanks for the support.

But do you know how I can follow the above process by API only, I don't want to call the link on the browser, I can get this thing directly By my code API.

Thanks again for the solution but helpful more if you could guide me.